# Error for ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, namespaces, exceldatareader

I am doing a project in C# and I have downloaded ExcelDataReader from codeplex and added it to my project reference. There is an error in namespace '`using Excel;`' though I have added `Excel`, `Excel.4.5`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to my project references. I'm getting error where I have written

```
 IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

The errors are quoted below:

> The type or namespace name 'ExcelDataReader' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) The name
>   'ExcelReaderFactory does not exist in the current context

How to deal with these errors?
Thank you in advance.

PS:- I have added '`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`' directive as well.

Comment: Try changing 'using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' to 'using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Comment: Try to install the excel reference via nugget. Nugget will do the job for you and then you should be able to resolve the dependency.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh i made changes as per ur suggestion and now I'm getting a new error "'DataTable' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable'."

Comment: @JBO I am new to .NET and C#...I don't know what nuggets are and how to use them

Comment: @RitujaNashikkar Ok, in your visual studio, you go to Tools > "Nuget Package Manager" > "Manage Nuget Packages For Solution". It will open a window where you will be able to look for the reference you need.

Comment: @JBO There is no such option in Tools...What to do now?

Comment: Look the answer posted by @Michal Turcyzn, it says the thing as me but more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Project** -> **Manage NuGet Packages...**, in opened window select *Browse* tab and type *Excel Data Reader*, install it, at the top of your class add `using Excel`. Then you will be able to use interface `IExcelDataReader`.

Here is the source:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1981566.aspx?The+type+or+namespace+name+IExcelDataReader+could+not+be+found

Comment: Sir, there is no option as 'Manage NuGet Packages' in Project tab. Not under any other tab in visual studio. Seems like I'm missing it in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project-> right click on References and click on Manage NuGet Packages a new tab would opened in your IDE if you are using VS 2015 or higher otherwise a pop window would open. enter package name and install.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of `ExcelDataReader` - like [2.1.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/2.1.2.3) - it uses an `Excel` namespace for itself, I mean that namespace is not related to Microsoft Office Excel, that I can suggest you to use alias for them:

```
using XlReader = Excel;
using Xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...

var excelReader = XlReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

But in newer version - like [3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) - its namespace changed to `ExcelDataReader`;
You can install the package of [ExcelDataReader 2.1.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/2.1.2.3) that will remove your compile exception.